# GameViewController to GameScene using presentScene with SKTransition

Tags: ios, swift3, sprite-kit

Tried to perform an SKTransition for the very first loading of GameScene from GameViewController but nothing seemed to happen. Can't we perform some transition while presenting a scene directly from the GameViewController? It seemed to me quite hilarious that the normal present scene is working but not the one with transition. Here is the code :

```
 class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

            let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
                // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
                scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
                //transition
                let transition = SKTransition.doorsOpenVertical(withDuration: 2)
                // Present the scene
                view.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)

            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
        }
    }
}

    class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.red
    }
}
```

Please solve the query.

Comment: Have you tried the following, self.view?.presentScene( scene: transition:transition) . I don't have my computer so I am not able to test this at the moment.

Comment: Just tried and the error is "Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'presentScene' ".

Comment: You need two scenes for transition to happen. That is why it is called a transition ;). See the definition of SKTransition.

Comment: So you mean to say we have no way to implement the required effect using Apple resources?

Comment: I see a few ways to accomplish this. It is not a big deal.  after the first scene is loaded: 1) run your own animation, or 2) run an SKTransition to the new scene. Both would work.

Comment: @Whirlwind Thnx man, can you please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42784531/presentscene-only-working-without-transition-over-a-collection-view , my main query is this.